# Understanding generic parameters with void return types

Tags: java, generics

I'm reviewing the source code for JDK classes.

The following method signature has me confused:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list);
```

Since the method doesn't return anything what are all the formal type parameters for?

How would the behavior of the method change if it's signature were only this:

```
public static void sort(List<T> list);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax:

```
public static void sort(List<T> list);
```

is not legal, because `T` has not been declared. The closest code with correct syntax is:

```
public static void sort(List<?> list);
```

This means the method will accept a List of any kind, but to *sort* the list, there must be some way to compare its elements - hence the original signature:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list);
```

which means each element can be compared with every other element via the `compareTo()` method.

The syntax:

```
void sort(List<? extends Comparable> list)
```

Is not nearly as useful - it just requires that the list contain objects that are Comparable, **but not necessarily to each other**. For example, such as list could contain a String and an Integer, both of which are Comparable, but not to each other - you could not meaningfully sort such a list. This is because the unknown type can be different for every element. However, by typing the method, the type can still be any type, but it's the *same* type for *all* elements of the list.

Comment: Could you please explain how this is any different from: `void sort(List<? extends Comparable> list)`

Comment: `by typing the method, the type can still be any type, but it's the same type for all elements of the list` That doesn't seem to be correct. I tried creating a sort method with both signatures and both accept a List containing Integer and String.

Answer (score 5):

If it was

```
public static void sort(List<T> list);
```

Java would have no idea the `T` type was supposed to be inferred from the argument. It'd look for a concrete class or interface named `T`, fail to find one, and spit compiler errors at you.

Comment: But isn't the type T supposed to be specified in class definition like: class MyClass<T> {}

Comment: There are more ways, how to specify T. Check this tutorial, it will teach you https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

Sierra & Bates SCJP:

> The strangest thing about generic methods is that you must declare the type variable BEFORE the return type of the method.

as others have said, the only way for

```
public static void sort(List<T> list);
```

to work is if there is actually a class named T, in which case the argument is like any other type declaration for variable.

It could also help to think about following example from Sierra & Bates. It shows that **formal type parameters are in order to avoid naming conflicts**:

```
class X { public <X> X(X x) {} }
```

> Yes, this works... there is no naming conflict between class names, type parameter placeholders, and variable identifiers.

Then we have other case:

```
void sort(List<? extends Comparable> list)
```

This case is known as [capture of a wildcard](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ402). Compiler takes type specification from the wildcard and creates anonymous type. The effect is the same like with explicit type specification except that the type can not be used in method implementation. You could imagine this as following pseudo-code:

```
<T_?001> void sort_?001(List<T_?001> list)
```

This case shows the other goal of **formal parameters - they allow the use of named type in method implementation**.

```
<T extends Comparable> void sort(List<T> list) {
  Iterator<T> it = list.iterator();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here type parameters are necessary just to restrict the input lists to only those which elements implement `Comparable` interface. Thanks to generic parameters if you pass `List` of non-comparable elements, it will be a compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

The type parameter is not about the method's *behaviour*, it's about the method's *signature*. The method accepts only Lists of Comparables. If you put in a List of non-Comparables, the `sort` will simply fail - makes sense, since if the elements can't be compared, how would you want to sort them?

Comment: If list should only be of Comparables whats wrong with: `void sort(List<? extends Comparable> list);`

Comment: Comparable is a generic type by itself. The JDK declaration ensures that you have a list of elements that are *mutually* comparable, not just partially.}

Sorry for not pointing that out more clearly.